# How many objects are being created in this code snippet

Tags: java, oop, methods

How many objects will be created for this code?

```java
class Main {
  int num;
  public static void gacemarks(Main m)
  {
    m.num += 10;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main m1 = new Main();
    Main m2 = m1;
    Main m3 = new Main();
    m2.num = 60;
    gacemarks(m2);
    System.out.println(m2);
  }
}
```

The answer is 2.
But I got 3.
m1 will be created, m2 refers to the same object
m3 is created newly and after the call, the m object is generated.

Comment: I know its a duplicate question. But i was not able to understand this code.

Comment: You are confusing object references (m1,m2,m3,m) with the objects they refer to. Objects are only created when a `new` statement (or `clone()` method, but that's another story) is called.

Comment: `m1` and `m2` refer to _one_ `Main` object. `m3` refers to another `Main` object. That's 2 `Main` objects total.

Comment: Try `System.out.println(m2.num)` after `gacemarks(m2);`. You should get 70 then because `m` is a reference to the object that is refered to by `m2`. (I assume that `System.out.println(m2)` doesn't show that because you didn't override `toString()`).

Comment: It did return the hex code !!! @Thomas

Comment: Yes that's what UI though, because you didn't override `toString()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of your code, the only two objects I see being explicitly created are the lines in which the `new` operator appears:

```
Main m1 = new Main();
Main m3 = new Main();
```

Here is a breakdown of which is happening in each line:

```
Main m1 = new Main();     // create new Main object 'm1'
Main m2 = m1;             // assign 'm2' to reference 'm1' (no new object)
Main m3 = new Main();     // create new Main object 'm3'
m2.num = 60;              // assign a field in 'm2' (no new object)
gacemarks(m2);            // repeatedly increment the 'm2.num' field (no new object)
System.out.println(m2);   // print 'm2' (no new object)
```

Comment: So, the call to the method does not create a new object, instead, it works on the same object reference being passed.

Comment: @NemalyPraveen Yes, that's right.  At least, when you reference the field `num`, you are incrementing the field of the object you passed in as a parameter.

Comment: @NemalyPraveen you might have heard that Java is call by value and this might be what's confusing you. That's true but there's a catch: when you pass a reference to an object, e.g. in `gacemarks(m2);`, the value is the reference itself, i.e. `m` is a copy of `m2` but they both are just references (similar to pointers in C++) to the same object.

Comment: Yup, @Thomas these can be referred to as object references being passed by value.

Answer (score 2):

> The answer is 2

That's right. Let's count together:

> `m1` will be created

Right, that's your object number one.

> `m2` refers to the same object

Right again, no new objects added; the count remains one.

> `m3` is created newly

That's your number two.

> and after the call, the `m` object is generated.

There's no `m` object in the code: when you pass `m2` to other methods, no copy is created. Hence the final count remains two.

Comment: So,  by code you are referring to the main method ??

Comment: @NemalyPraveen no he's refering to all your code. `m` is a reference to the object that has been passed so it doesn't refer to a _new_ object.

Comment: @NemalyPraveen Yes, that's where all the action is happening. No code is executed unless `main` invokes it, directly or indirectly.

Answer (score 2):

Although there are two `Main` objects created directly in the code (with `new` operator) one can argue that `System.out.println(m2);` creates an additional `String` object due to `toString()` being called.

Comment: Good catch +1.  Maybe this should be an interview question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen another one could be `String[] args` array created when calling `main()`. It's hard to tell what the question is really about.

Comment: Actually, you're opening a Pandora's box, because you don't know how many objects are created there. It depends on the implementation. There is a string created in `Integer.toHexString()`, and then it's concatenated to the other stuff like class name (which may or may not create an object) to create another string.

Comment: Well I understand "The answer is 2. But I got 3." as "The _correct_ answer is 2. But I got 3, which is wrong." - so I'd doubt all those other objects, including the string, are taken into account. :)

Comment: I guess it usually refers to the objects being created by the user. Not the ones that are generated automatically.